# Generating regular time series from irregular time series in pandas

Tags: python, numpy, pandas, time-series, data-analysis

I have a data analysis task in which I want to analyze the real time service logs. Could you please help me how to do this in Pandas?

My initial dataframe look like this:
[image]

I want to generate time series for each service name and make a correlation analysis based on this.

How can I divide this dataframe into different dataframes(indexed with time slot) for each service name by aggregating their respective data as shown below?
[image]

Ps:I have seen similar questions, but I believe my question is different because I want to generate many time series from a dataframe. And sorry in advance if this is an easy one, I am new to Pandas :)

Here is my Dataframe as code:

```
                ERRORCODE   ERRORTEXT   SERVICENAME REQTDURATION    RESPTDURATION   HOSTDURATION

10:00:27:000        NaN        NaN      serviceA       0              1             4612    
10:00:27:822        NaN        NaN      serviceB       0              1             14994   
10:01:27:622        -1        'Timeout' serviceA       1              0             7695    
10:01:27:323        NaN        NaN      serviceD       0              1             2612
10:01:27:755        NaN        NaN      serviceA       0              1             1612
10:02:27:666        -5        'Timeout' serviceA       0              1             11612
10:02:27:111        NaN        NaN      serviceB       0              1             111112
10:02:27:333        NaN        NaN      serviceC       0              1             412
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Starting with:

```
                 ERRORCODE  ERRORTEXT SERVICENAME  REQTDURATION  RESPTDURATION  \
10:00:27:000        NaN        NaN    serviceA             0              1   
10:00:27:822        NaN        NaN    serviceB             0              1   
10:01:27:622         -1  'Timeout'    serviceA             1              0   
10:01:27:323        NaN        NaN    serviceD             0              1   
10:01:27:755        NaN        NaN    serviceA             0              1   
10:02:27:666         -5  'Timeout'    serviceA             0              1   
10:02:27:111        NaN        NaN    serviceB             0              1   
10:02:27:333        NaN        NaN    serviceC             0              1   

              HOSTDURATION  
10:00:27:000          4612  
10:00:27:822         14994  
10:01:27:622          7695  
10:01:27:323          2612  
10:01:27:755          1612  
10:02:27:666         11612  
10:02:27:111        111112  
10:02:27:333           412
```

Converting `index` to `DateTimeIndex`:

```
df.index = pd.to_datetime(df.index, format='%H:%M:%S:%f')
```

And then looping over `SERVICENAME` groups:

```
for service, data in df.groupby('SERVICENAME'):
    service_result = pd.concat([data.groupby(pd.TimeGrouper('Min')).size(), data.groupby(pd.TimeGrouper('Min'))['REQTDURATION', 'RESPTDURATION', 'HOSTDURATION'].mean()], axis=1)
    service_result.columns = ['ERRORCOUNT', 'AVGREQTURATION', 'AVGRESPTDURATION', 'AVGHOSTDURATION']
    service_result.index = service_result.index.time
```

yields:

```
serviceA

          ERRORCOUNT  AVGREQTURATION  AVGRESPTDURATION  AVGHOSTDURATION
10:00:00           1             0.0               1.0           4612.0
10:01:00           2             0.5               0.5           4653.5
10:02:00           1             0.0               1.0          11612.0

 serviceB
          ERRORCOUNT  AVGREQTURATION  AVGRESPTDURATION  AVGHOSTDURATION
10:00:00           1               0                 1            14994
10:01:00           0             NaN               NaN              NaN
10:02:00           1               0                 1           111112

 serviceC
          ERRORCOUNT  AVGREQTURATION  AVGRESPTDURATION  AVGHOSTDURATION
10:02:00           1               0                 1              412

 serviceD
          ERRORCOUNT  AVGREQTURATION  AVGRESPTDURATION  AVGHOSTDURATION
10:01:00           1               0                 1             2612
```

Comment: when I run this i got following exception, am I missing something ?  ValueError: too many values to unpack

Comment: originating in which line?

Comment: at the beginning of foor loop. df is my data frame object right ? it says can not iterate data frame like this i guess ?

Comment: there should be something like df.iterrows() ?

Comment: should have been `.groupby('SERVICENAME')`, see updated answer. There was also a paren typo in the first line in the first line.

Comment: Added sample output using your data.

Comment: Thanks for the effort, I appreciate much. But i could not verify that answer was what i was looking for. In my case I should have different data frame objects for each service name and for each data frame there should be a respecting time series.When I print your code it only prints one row for each frame. may be my index object is not correct, i will check and inform you.

Comment: Updated with full output. There is only one `row` indeed for cases `C` and `D` where the source came with a single instance.